# Can POSIX-level file system APIs bridge between OS X, iOS, and Android?

Tags: android, ios, macos, file-io, posix

I have a legacy Mac Carbon-based application that I have ported to 64-bit (Lion and beyond).  The application made heavy use of the FS family of functions and structures at a C-level, including references to Finder.h.  I managed to cobble together something that works with the OS X 10.7+ SDKs, albeit with many deprecated functions.

Now I am trying to port the application to iOS (and in the future Android as well).  Since iOS doesn't have the classic Mac OS roots, many of the FS structures and the ideology of being built around Finder are non-existent.

My question is it possible to build a cross-platform file system layer on top of C POSIX-supported functions for the three platforms I mentioned?  I know neither iOS or Android is certified POSIX compatible, though they behave very much like POSIX systems.

I have a large chunk of code to purge Mac OS dependency from at my application level, and my gut tells me it will be cheaper in the long run to try and handle file access, folder enumeration, and symlink resolution with C-level APIs.

I've disregarded NSFileManager and Core Foundation methods as options because this is just going to require another abstraction layer and a rewrite for when I eventually move to Android.

I'm not too familiar with POSIX-like environments yet, so I appreciate the advice of a veteran.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have done a lot of cross platform development (Palm OS, Windows Mobile, BlackBerry, iOS, Android, Mac OSX, Windows 7, and Windows App Store Apps) and I now recommend creating a fully native app for iOS and Android.  There are ways to do cross platform development between the two platforms, but I don't think it is worth going done those paths.  Create fully native apps on each platform and take full advantage of the APIs iOS and Android gives you.

Comment: Ok, so you mean there is a way to use POSIX to handle file I/O on all three platforms, you just don't recommend it?  By "fully native" I assume you mean to use Core Foundation on iOS, and Android File Manager routines?  I want to avoid having 3 separate copies of code to manage, so in my git repository I hope to work from a single codebase (and a single XCode project right now with iOS/OS X).

Comment: I haven't tried POSIX to handle file I/O.  I have tried other ways that do work for file I/O.  I wouldn't recommend using them though.